# TSQL - Changing Name of Case While Looping In A Stored Proceedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, loops, dynamic, sql-server-2014

I am using a stored procedure to add columns to a grid on a Windows Form.
I am having a problem dynamically adding new columns to this grid.
I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

What I am attempting to do is use a variable declared in SQL to name each column... Here is an example.

```
@Date as date
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @cnt as int = 0;
DECLARE @name as varchar(3); 
WHILE @cnt < 12 
BEGIN 
SELECT  SUM(Price) as Price, Type,
SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.myTable.Date = @Date THEN dbo.myTable.Price ELSE NULL END) AS @name 
FROM myTable
WHERE (Date BETWEEN @Date AND  DATEADD(dd, 60, @Date)) 
GROUP BY Type
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1 
    SET @name = @name + CONVERT(varchar(1),@cnt) 
END;
```

I am attempting to create a loop and change the name of each case statement as I pull them into the grid but the way I'm implementing it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is what my desired output is...
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lmQA.png)

One way I am able to get my desired output is creating multiple case statements...

```
SELECT  SUM(Price) as Price, Type,
SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.myTable.Date = DATEADD(dd,1,@Date) THEN dbo.myTable.Price ELSE NULL END) AS D1,
SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.myTable.Date = DATEADD(dd,2,@Date) THEN dbo.myTable.Price ELSE NULL END) AS D2,
SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.myTable.Date = DATEADD(dd,3,@Date) THEN dbo.myTable.Price ELSE NULL END) AS D3,
...
SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.myTable.Date = DATEADD(dd,60,@Date) THEN dbo.myTable.Price ELSE NULL END) AS D60
FROM myTable
WHERE (Date BETWEEN @Date AND  DATEADD(dd, 60, @Date)) 
GROUP BY Type
END;
```

I am curious if there is a cleaner way to do this utilizing a loop like I attempted to do in the above code.

Is there a way to implement what I am trying to get done or should I look for another solution?

Thank you.

Comment: What you are wanting to do will take dynamic sql because the column names would have to be hard coded otherwise.  But you the above syntax is also incorrect to select something.  You also shouldn't need a loop.  I suggest adding some example data and a desired data set (or 2) that people can answer more specifically on.

Comment: show us your table structure with data and your expected result, it will help us to give you better solution.

Comment: As a rule, questions should not reference external images. If the image vanishes then the question likely becomes useless to other users. You don't mention what database software you're using. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Are you looking for something that `pivot` can do?

Comment: Examples of your starting tables so we can understand the transformation you want to do?

Comment: Thank you guys. I have made some changed and added a query that gives me my desired output so you have a better idea of what I am looking for.

Comment: @nick, I think I finally figure it out but again providing example data from your myTable would have been useful.  Will you always want to do 60 days or will the number of days differ? Are you wanting a cummulative total or just the total on a specific day.  e.g. does d2 include d1 or just d2 because your top code suggests it includes.  And yes this can be done without dynamic sql but your question was unclear.   Also it can be done with dynamic sql nice and neatly as well...

Comment: You query (SP?) produces at least 12 tables (rowsets). How do you plan to use them to "populate grid"?

Comment: @Matt, What data would I be able to provide? The date may differ but my current task is 60 days. The days will be accumulated under the "Amount" column which is grouped by an "Amount Type" I failed to mention this for I didn't think it would be important but I am seeing now that I should have. So the totals will be accumulated under the "Amount" column but each amount will fall under it's respective "D#" column. So say I could have a total amount of 500 with an "Amount" of 100 in D4 and an amount of 400 in D9. Sorry for the poor layout of my question this is my first time asking a Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the while loop should work for you.

```
declare 
@x varchar(2) = 1,
@sql varchar(8000),
@Date varchar(30) ='2016-01-01',
@y varchar(2) = 6

while @x < @y
begin

set @sql = isnull(@sql,'')+',SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.myTable.Date = DATEADD(dd,' +@x +' ,'+''''+@Date+''''+') THEN dbo.myTable.Price ELSE NULL END) AS D'+@x + '  '

set @x = @x +1

end 

set @sql = 'SELECT  SUM(Price) as Price '+@sql +' FROM myTable WHERE (Date BETWEEN '+''''+@Date+''''+' AND  DATEADD(dd,'+ @y+',' +''''+@Date+''''+')) '

exec( @sql)
```

which builds this query

```
 SELECT SUM(Price) AS Price
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN dbo.myTable.DATE = DATEADD(dd, 1, '2016-01-01')
                THEN dbo.myTable.Price
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS D1
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN dbo.myTable.DATE = DATEADD(dd, 2, '2016-01-01')
                THEN dbo.myTable.Price
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS D2
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN dbo.myTable.DATE = DATEADD(dd, 3, '2016-01-01')
                THEN dbo.myTable.Price
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS D3
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN dbo.myTable.DATE = DATEADD(dd, 4, '2016-01-01')
                THEN dbo.myTable.Price
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS D4
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN dbo.myTable.DATE = DATEADD(dd, 5, '2016-01-01')
                THEN dbo.myTable.Price
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS D5
FROM myTable
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND DATEADD(dd, 6, '2016-01-01'))
```

Comment: Thank you Kostya! This is exactly what I was looking for, makes so much sense I can't believe I didn't think of it myself!                                               Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
-----This section is just to get me some test data to show you how it works
DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE ([Date] DATE, AmountType VARCHAR(10), Price INT)
DECLARE @Date DATE = (GETDATE() - 1)
DECLARE @Price INT = 1

WHILE @Price < 61
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AmountType VARCHAR(10)
    SET @AmountType = CASE
       WHEN @Price%4 = 0 THEN 'Type 1'
       WHEN @Price%4 = 1 THEN 'Type 2'
       WHEN @Price%4 = 2 THEN 'Type 3'
       ELSE 'Type 4'
    END

    INSERT INTO @MyTable ([Date], AmountType, Price) VALUES (DATEADD(d,@Price,@Date), @AmountType, @Price * 4)
    INSERT INTO @MyTable ([Date], AmountType, Price) VALUES (DATEADD(d,@Price,@Date), @AmountType, @Price * 2)

    SET @Price += 1
END

SET @Date = GETDATE()

------------------Build A DateTable On The Fly-----------------
DECLARE @Dates AS TABLE ([Date] DATE, DayNum VARCHAR(4))
DECLARE @I INT = 0
WHILE @I < 60
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Dates ([Date], DayNum) VALUES (DATEADD(d,@I,@Date),'D' + CAST(@I + 1 AS VARCHAR(4)))
    SET @I += 1
END

--You can use c# to pivot this data probably a lot easier if you do just grab your query like this
SELECT
    d.DayNum
    ,t.AmountType
    ,Price = SUM(ISNULL(t.Price,0))
FROM
    @Dates d
    LEFT JOIN @MyTable t
    ON d.[Date] = t.[Date]
GROUP BY
    d.DayNum
    ,t.AmountType
ORDER BY
    d.DayNum

---- If you don't want to do the pivot in your application then you can do this:


SELECT
    AmountType
    ,D1 = ISNULL(D1,0), D2 = ISNULL(D2,0), D3 = ISNULL(D3,0), D4 = ISNULL(D4,0), D5 = ISNULL(D5,0), D6 = ISNULL(D6,0), D7 = ISNULL(D7,0), D8 = ISNULL(D8,0), D9 = ISNULL(D9,0), D10 = ISNULL(D10,0), D11 = ISNULL(D11,0), D12 = ISNULL(D12,0), D13 = ISNULL(D13,0), D14 = ISNULL(D14,0), D15 = ISNULL(D15,0), D16 = ISNULL(D16,0), D17 = ISNULL(D17,0), D18 = ISNULL(D18,0), D19 = ISNULL(D19,0), D20 = ISNULL(D20,0), D21 = ISNULL(D21,0), D22 = ISNULL(D22,0), D23 = ISNULL(D23,0), D24 = ISNULL(D24,0), D25 = ISNULL(D25,0), D26 = ISNULL(D26,0), D27 = ISNULL(D27,0), D28 = ISNULL(D28,0), D29 = ISNULL(D29,0), D30 = ISNULL(D30,0), D31 = ISNULL(D31,0), D32 = ISNULL(D32,0), D33 = ISNULL(D33,0), D34 = ISNULL(D34,0), D35 = ISNULL(D35,0), D36 = ISNULL(D36,0), D37 = ISNULL(D37,0), D38 = ISNULL(D38,0), D39 = ISNULL(D39,0), D40 = ISNULL(D40,0), D41 = ISNULL(D41,0), D42 = ISNULL(D42,0), D43 = ISNULL(D43,0), D44 = ISNULL(D44,0), D45 = ISNULL(D45,0), D46 = ISNULL(D46,0), D47 = ISNULL(D47,0), D48 = ISNULL(D48,0), D49 = ISNULL(D49,0), D50 = ISNULL(D50,0), D51 = ISNULL(D51,0), D52 = ISNULL(D52,0), D53 = ISNULL(D53,0), D54 = ISNULL(D54,0), D55 = ISNULL(D55,0), D56 = ISNULL(D56,0), D57 = ISNULL(D57,0), D58 = ISNULL(D58,0), D59 = ISNULL(D59,0), D60 = ISNULL(D60,0)
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          DayNum
          ,AmountType
          ,Price
       FROM
          @Dates d
          LEFT JOIN @MyTable t
          ON d.[Date] = t.[Date]
    ) s
PIVOT
    (
       SUM(Price)
       FOR DayNum IN ([D1],[D2],[D3],[D4],[D5],[D6],[D7],[D8],[D9],[D10],[D11],[D12],[D13],[D14],[D15],[D16],[D17],[D18],[D19],[D20],[D21],[D22],[D23],[D24],[D25],[D26],[D27],[D28],[D29],[D30],[D31],[D32],[D33],[D34],[D35],[D36],[D37],[D38],[D39],[D40],[D41],[D42],[D43],[D44],[D45],[D46],[D47],[D48],[D49],[D50],[D51],[D52],[D53],[D54],[D55],[D56],[D57],[D58],[D59],[D60])
    ) as p
```

To answer some of the comments between us.  We were looking for exactly what your last comment was a table or part there of that showed the structure of the table including Date, AmountType, Price, etc.  That way we could understand how you where arriving at D1, D2, etc. Run a query against @MyTable to see the data example providing a few rows of that would have solved my and others curiosity.

My personal opinion is that you should probably look at a robust dynamic SQL or .net solution to pivot the dataset rather than hard coding to handle issues such as missing dates, changing number of days, etc.

The solution I presented here uses no dynamic sql is hard coded for 60 days and shows you 2 different datasets for you to choose from.  I also made an assumption that you where looking for consecutive dates so this query takes into account that a price might be missing during that time and will treat it as such.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Matt. This is very helpful information and is definitely going to be a good reference for me. However I was able to utilize dynamic SQL to get my designed output. I see you suggested I do some research on the TSQL language to tackle more complex topics. Would this question be considered a complex topic? Also if you have any references you like you use I would greatly appreciate it. I thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: It's not that the question or requirement is complex just that most of the time it will require some techniques that are less used or desirable.  Dynamic SQL for example takes certain database permissions and is typically not as desirable when not needed also because of execution plans.  PIVOT and UNPIVOT are usually application layer functions. Anything XML leads to interesting answers. In one of the edits you wrote you were a SQL nob. So tackling these is kind of like running before crawling is all I hope you didn't take that negatively and I will edit it out.

Comment: I didn't take it negatively at all. I was just curious as to what is a "Simple" and a "Complex" topic because I'm not sure how to quite judge my skill in SQL so I was curious as to if this was a "simple topic" that any semi-skilled"SQL user would know how to implement.

Comment: Got it not totally sure what to write but I would say if you understand the answers you are well on your way to being just fine at SQL.  Your original question showed a reasonable understanding of querying but left room for some knowledge of how to move beyond that into the more dynamic tasks but truthfully the latter is usually developed out of necessity for us users that focus on multiple layers of tiered applications.